# Aligning uneven rows in div based table

Tags: html, css, image

I have a table built with divs that uses images as the cell data. If I have a missing image, I want to essentially center the other images in the row as such:

All images:

```
xxxxx
xxxxx
```

Missing images (2 in second row):

```
xxxxx
 xxx
```

Currently, I can only get the results to align left:

```
xxxxx
xxx
```

css:

```
.table
{
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-right:15px;
    display:  table;
    width:auto;
    border-spacing:0px;
}

.row
{
   display:table-row;
   width:auto;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
}

.cell
{
    float:left;
    display:table-column;
    width:auto;
}
```

I tried an auto margin left/right for row, but no dice. Any suggestions?

**Edit**

```
  <div class="table">
         <div class="row">
            #if ($has1)
                <div class="cell"><a href="#1"><img src="1.jpg" width="138"/></a></div>
            #end
            #if ($has2)
                <div class="cell"><a href="2"><img src="2.jpg" width="138"/></a></div>
            #end
            #if ($has3)
                <div class="cell"><a href="#3"><img src="3.jpg" width="138"/></a></div>
            #end

        </div>
         <div class="row">
            #if ($has4)
                <div class="cell"><a href="#4"><img src="4.jpg" width="138"/></a></div>
            #end
            #if ($has5)
                <div class="cell"><a href="5"><img src="5.jpg" width="138"/></a></div>
            #end
            #if ($has6)
                <div class="cell"><a href="#6"><img src="6.jpg" width="138"/></a></div>
            #end

        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: did you try "margin :0 auto"?

Comment: Yeah - No luck. Same results.

Comment: can you post the html? a jsfiddle?

Comment: Added html. Using apache velocity templates within the divs as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, try this:

```
.table
{
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-right:15px;
    display:  table;
    width:auto;
    border-spacing:0px;
}

.row
{
   display:table-row;
   width:auto;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   text-align:center;
}

.cell
{
    /*display:table-column;*/
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;
}​
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/JARQs/

Comment: This is dead right. Oddly, all my images are stacking on top of each other. Only way that doesn't happen is if the float property is assigned to the cell. Any idea?

Comment: Mmm, try changing the "display:inline-block;" with "display:table-column;".
I have only added the "text-align:center" in "rows", and "killed" the "float:left" in "cell"

Comment: Hmm.. No luck either. I'm starting to wonder if the Velocity templates are causing problems here.

Comment: Sorry for not addressing that. I changed that property, still no luck.

Comment: the last thing I can think of is you post a link with your work, so I can see what is missing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.row
{
   display:table;
   width:auto;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   text-align:center;
}
```

You can also use a container with display:table css and mantain original .row css class